# Configure IBM Cloud Application with "request of client certificate"

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I need to configure an application to accept connection only from client with a certificate, the client should be ApiGateway.

I followed [this](https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/2016/07/06/securing-apic-bm-app-mutual-tls/) step by step tutorial. But when I should upload a certificate and enable a checkbox called "**Enable request of client certificate**" in upload dialog box it disappear.

I tried with many browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) on a Mac. I'm quite that this not depend on browser, so now how can do the same thing?

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the given task needs to be separated into two activities.

1. Client with certificate
2. A client with DNS APIgateway

**Client with Certificate**

In general, when we create an API, we expose with a gateway via HTTP protocol which has some signed certificate (Production). Please provide that public certificate to the consumer of your API. And you can test this using postman, we have an option of SSL certificate upload in Postman, make a use of it for testing.

**Client with DNS Name**

For this, in Datapower (API Gateway), you can create an Access control list following this [IBM documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21283002). Access control list is something, we allow or restrict the host that we consume the services exposed using Datapower.